# i cant pass the parameter id on the URI slim framework

Tags: php, parameters, routes, frameworks, slim

i have an update form to update the product details :

```
<form action="{{ path_for('product.update', {id: product.id}) }}" method="get">
// another fields
<input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="PUT">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="update">
```

routes :

```
$app->get('/admin/product/edit/{id}', ['maimana\Controllers\AdminController','editupdateProduct'])->setName('product.edit');
$app->get('/admin/product/update/product/{id}', ['maimana\Controllers\AdminController','updateProduct'])->setName('product.update');
```

and the controller :

public function updateProduct($id, Request $request, Response $response){

```
  $product = $this->product->where('id',$id)->first()->update([
    'title' => $request->getParam('title'),
    'category' => $request->getParam('category'),
    'slug' => $request->getParam('slug'),
    'description' => $request->getParam('description'),
    'price' => $request->getParam('price'),
    'image' => $request->getParam('image'),
    'stock' => $request->getParam('stock')
  ]);

  return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('admin.product'));


}
```

everytime i hit the update button, i cant pass the parameter is automatically and it turns PAGE NOT FOUND. but when i add the id manually it works and redirect back to admin.product.

please help me im getting stuck for about 4 days and i need this for my college task

Answer (score 0):

Slim also uses Restful URLs it seems. When you have the _method set to 'put' in the form and sends the request, it will interpret it as a PUT request rather than a GET. Since this is your college task, I think I've helped you with 99% of the problem here.

Comment: thank you for the answer! but when i change the GET method to PUT on routes it still not work and when i delete the PUT method inside the form it doesnt work either. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well first you should really explain more fully about what's not working. still 404? then check your html's form action url.

Comment: the problem is when i click the submit button it doesnt read the parameter id. it turns like this public/admin/product/update/?title=test&category=&slug=&description=&price=&image=&stock=&submit=update but when i add the id number manually after update/ it works fine. i dont know what to fix

Comment: Can you paste your generated action url here plz.. I think it's missing the id there.

Comment: yes you're right. it's missing the id. it goes like this /public/admin/product/update/

Comment: check why the id isn't passed over